# Handlebars - Decompile handlebars compiled code to handlebars template

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

Is it possible to decompile Handlebars precompiled code to Handlebars template?

Possibly convert something like this:

`function program2(depth0, data) {
            var buffer = '', stack1;
            data.buffer.push('<div ');
            ......
            data.buffer.push('</div></div>');
            return buffer;
        }`

to

```
<div>{{name}}</div>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is currently no built-in way to do so.

One solution would be to write a function that traverses the compiled code, look for where the HTML is being pushed and then put that HTML back together (reverse engineer the function, essentially).

There's one drawback: the compiled templates use the `depth0` variable to store the passed in from your model/object. You can see that and the other objects being passed in as parameters where each compiled template is being instantiated, IE::

```
App.Templates = function (Handlebars, depth0, helpers, partials, data) { ... }
```

So you would have to follow how each piece of HTML is rendered and find the variable names that correspond to the expressions where they are pushed in as the `stack` variables. You'd need to get the name of the variable used so you can add back the attribute of each Handlebars block in the template (ie: `{{myData}}`) as well as the expression used (and if it is a block expression).

Say I have a simple template:

```
{{#if stuff}}
    <div id="General" class="content-section">
    <p>{{myData}}</p>
    </div>
{{/if}}
```

The `depth0` object would contain `stuff` and `myData`. They're being used inside of the template like so (this is not a working example, I edited a template to show you what it'd look like):

```
buffer += "\r\n\r\n<div id=\"General\" class=\"content-section\">\r\n"
    + escapeExpression(((stack1 = ((stack1 = (depth0 && depth0.stuff)),
    stack1 == null || stack1 === false ? stack1 : stack1.myData)), 
    typeof stack1 === functionType ? stack1.apply(depth0) : stack1))
```

Hopefully that helps a bit - it is certainly doable if you want to put the work in.

Comment: Your answer looks like the way to go ahead. Thanks!

Comment: @Bhoomi if you'd be interested in collaborating on an open source project to do this, I'd be more than happy to help put it together.  You can find my contact information in my profile.